# New domain that's redirected from an old domain using a 301 has not been indexed

Tags: google-search-console, redirects, 301-redirect

I started a site `example.in` but I want to redirect it to `example.com`.

I have established a `301` redirect and submitted a change of address request in Google Webmaster Tools. But when I am searching `site:example.in`, search results for `example.in` are being displayed, but not for `example.com`. What should I do?

Comment: Can you add a bit more detail? I am not sure of your exact scenario.

Comment: means why google is not displaying search result for example.com , i have submitted redirection request and established 31 redirect from old domain to new domain

Answer (score 1):

This will not change at the same moment you issue a redirect. It will take time, as google needs to reindex the site first for it to update new links. It's a waiting game, so you will see the old links for a while.